# Requesting aliased :guifont rendering in Vim on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, fonts, gvim, anti-aliasing

Non-AA font rendering seems available everywhere except for *Windows*.

- In *MacVim*, this is possivle via `noantialias`.
- When using GTK2 front-end, the same can be achieved by adding `antialias=false` to the *fontconfig* query, e.g.: `Courier New:size=12:antialias=false:rgba=rgb`.
- For Motif, Athena and GTK1 front-ends, aliased rendering is the only option.

But how do I request it in the GUI version of *Vim* on Windows (`gui_win32`)?

Answer (score 1):

Anti aliasing for the Windows build of `gvim` can be controlled via the ['renderoptions'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'renderoptions') setting. To have this work, this needs a `+directx` support to be compiled in. Check in the output of `:version`.

For how to configure it properly, you most likely want to tune the `taamode` suboption and set it according to the values defined by Microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/api/d2d1/ne-d2d1-d2d1_text_antialias_mode

Note: Although the `renderoptions` can provide a much better font rendering on Windows, there is a bug with certain multi-byte characters and the statusline, as mentioned in the corresponding issue https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1520 (I am not sure if this only affects the statusline or other parts of the rendering as well)

This means, it basically breaks for me when using vim with a fancy statusline plugin like [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline)